# How to upgrade Magento from 2.1.7 to 2.2.2 only from backend

Tags: magento2.2, magento-2.1.7, migration

[image]

I also tried to go to Component manger but it is spinning all the time.

[image]

And when I access to this url (got it from internet search)

> https://www.domain.com/setup/index.php/dependency-check/component-dependency

I am getting this error:

```
An error occurred during execution; please try again later.

===================================================
Additional information:

Zend\Json\Exception\RuntimeException

File:
```

public_html/vendor/zendframework/zend-json/src

Comment: check your php version now magento 2.2.2 support 7.0.2 php version so please check it.

Comment: PHP Version - 7.0.27 is using present..

Comment: I have done upgrade fro magento 2 through command line previously, but not working from backend - Getting Component Dependency Error.

Answer (score 0):

Run below commands in sequence.

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.2 --no-update
composer update
rm -rf var/cache/*
rm -rf var/page_cache/*
rm -rf var/generation/*
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento cache:clean
bin/magento cache:flush
```

Then check it will works !!

Comment: Need to update only from backend, not using commands.

Comment: Hi
I have updated magento through the command line...
When i checked the version ,it was successfully upgraded to 2.2.2, but while accessing the frontend and backend ..Iam getting the 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: And in reindex I am getting the error: Table "CatelogInventory_Stock_Status_Replica" doesnot exist.
Do any one have experience this, please suggest ....Iam stuck with the magento upgrade for days.

Catalog Rule Index, Catalog Product Rule Index and Stock Indexes are failed.